# Import functions from one ipynb file to another in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was trying to import functions from one notebook file to another in the most simplest way:

[image]

As you can see the files are in the same folder but I still get this error. Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: I don't think you can import code from notebook files, only from regular python scripts (text files with the `.py` extension). Move the functions into a `predictions1.py` file and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, import `funb()` located in `b.ipynb` in `a.ipynb`.

1. install module: `pip install ipynb`
2. in `a.ipynb`:

   ```
    import ipynb
    from ipynb.fs.full.b import funb         // ipynb.fs.full.<notebook_name>
    funb()
   ```

See result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the `%run` magic command.

You could store your functions in a sort of library notebook and use the following line to import them in your current notebook:

```
%run ./func_library_notebook.ipynb
```